# Camunda 7.2: how to configure camunda-webapp to work on a different host than engine

Tags: business-process-management, camunda

I'm still very new to Camunda. Maybe I've missed something obvious. But is there a simple way to configure camunda-webapp-jboss-7.2.0 (admin, cockpit, tasklist) to run on a different host than camunda-engine?

E.g., I have a host "A" with camunda-bpm-wildfly-7.2.0 and want to deploy camunda-webapp-jboss-7.2.0.war on host "B" (vanilla wildfly). Is there a way in webapp to configure the engines hostname or IP or baseURL? I assume, webapp uses REST API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a deployment scenario is not possible at the moment. The webapp always needs at least an embedded process engine that is configured against the correct database. The best you can do is use the [standalone webapp](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/user-guide/#introduction-download-standalone-web-application-distribution).

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the camunda server by using the shared process engine way of deployment by using springboot starters of camunda